# Activities overview current workspace only

Tags: shortcut-keys, workspaces, activities-overview

Hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key shows me all activities from all workspaces. I would like to have an option to show all activities from just the **current workspace**, either with another shortcut or by changing the behavior of the current shortcut.

I'm using 2 monitors. I noticed when the activities are on my laptop (primary) screen the overview is actually restricted to the current workspace. However it always shows all activities from external though. Can I change the behavior for this screen as well?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is confusion in terminology. In Gnome Shell, different workspaces are not necessarily put on a different screen. By default, Gnome Shell shows the activities of the current workspace only. You can switch to different workspaces in the activities overview using the desktop icons to the right. Thus, *the activities you see do belong to a single workspace*, even if some of the windows are positioned on the second monitor.

Gnome does not put separate workspaces on separate monitors. By default, a second monitor is an extension of the first workspace. When you switch workspaces, the next workspaces are shown on your primary monitor. The extended space of your first workspace remains visible on the second monitor.

There is no obvious way to change this behavior, except for using Gnome Shell extensions if available. There actually is currently an extension that does what you are looking for: [Current screen only on window switcher by mmai](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1437/current-screen-only-for-alternate-tab/) aims to show only the windows (of the current workspace) on the current monitor in the overview.

Just for information, there is also a well known gnome Shell extension, [Multi Monitors Add-On by spin83](https://extensions.gnome.org/#page=3) that allows the launcher to appear on any of the monitors, so switching between workspaces on the secondary monitor also becomes possible.