# How to make Activities overview only shown on current monito?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, multiple-monitors, activities-overview

I am using two monitors, one at the left for screen-recording, another primary at the right for other work. It works fine but when I hit Super key, the Activities overview is shown on the left screen. I want it to be shown on the right screen, so that my application list not be recorded.

I have read some earlier questions but neither works:

- [Activities overview current workspace only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1278781/activities-overview-current-workspace-only)
- [Ubuntu 19.10, dual monitor: GNOME Activities overview messed up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182937/ubuntu-19-10-dual-monitor-gnome-activities-overview-messed-up)

One answer suggests using the Dash to Dock extension, but I can not accept the side effect that a Dock appears:

- [Activities on multiple displays in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263309/activities-on-multiple-displays-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is somewhat old, but this was bugging me as well on Ubuntu 22.04.

For me this answer worked: https://askubuntu.com/a/1400955